# how to parse xml using soap web service

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a device which periodically sends xml file to a specific webservice. Also I have a web service. My web service read this xml.

My Web service definition is :

```
@Name("myWebService")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.abc.com.tr/")

public class MyWebService {
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;
    @WebMethod()
    public String DeviceStatus(@WebParam(name = "SP") SP SP) {..}
```

My class structure is SP.java, MODULES.java, MODULE.java, SENSORS.java, SENSOR.java

Before there was no problem but when the incoming xml's namespace definition has changed my webservice started to give error like :  can not find child element SP

before the incoming xml was :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:abc="http://www.abc.com.tr/">
<soap:Body>
<abc:DeviceStatus>
<SP>
<VERSION>1.2</VERSION>
<MODULES>
<MODULE><NAME>name</NAME><TYPE>1</TYPE>
<SENSORS>
<SENSOR><ID>0</ID><NAME>Input</NAME></SENSOR>
</SENSORS>
</MODULE>
</MODULES>
</SP>
</abc:DeviceStatus></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

now the incoming xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<DeviceStatus xmlns="http://www.abc.com.tr/">
<SP>.......
```

I am looking forward your replies. thanks...